# remove debug log from hadoop console output

Tags: logging, hadoop, console, mapreduce, config

I want to remove DEBUG Messages from my hadoop console output. I have already set

```
 export HADOOP_ROOT_LOGGER=WARN,DRFA
 export HADOOP_JHS_LOGGER=WARN,DRFA
```

in the hadoop-env.sh file and

```
hadoop.root.logger=WARN,console
hadoop.security.logger=WARN,console
```

in the log4j.properties file in hadoop/bin

Currently when I run
    **`hadoop fs -lsr /directory/`** 
 the output is the below. I only want to see the actual files rather than all the debug/info statements. thanks.

```
12:03:58.408 [sendParams-0] DEBUG org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client - IPC Client (47)     connection to ...
12:03:58.408 [IPC Client (47) connection to xxxxxx from xxxx]         DEBUG org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client - IPC Client (47) connection to ...
12:03:58.408 [main] DEBUG org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RPC - Call: getListing 1
drwxr-xr-x   - abc supergroup          0 2013-02-21 18:01 /user/xxxx/res
12:03:58.409 [sendParams-0] DEBUG org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client - IPC Client (47)      connection to xxxxxx/xxxxx from xxxx sending #13
12:03:58.410 [IPC Client (47) connection to xxxxxx/xxxxx from xxxx]     DEBUG org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client - IPC Client (47) connection to      xxxxxx/xxxxxx from xxxx got value #13
12:03:58.410 [main] DEBUG org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RPC - Call: getListing 1
drwxr-xr-x   - xxxxx supergroup          0 2013-02-21 12:20 /user/xxxxx/rhipeTest
12:03:58.410 [sendParams-0] DEBUG org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client - IPC Client (47)       connection to xxxxx/xxxx from tenglin sending #14
12:03:58.411 [IPC Client (47) connection to xxxxxx from xxxxx]        DEBUG org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client - IPC Client (47) connection to        xxxxxx/xxxxxx from xxxxxxx got value #14
12:03:58.411 [main] DEBUG org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RPC - Call: getListing 1
-rw-r--r--   2 xxxxx supergroup       1229 2013-02-21 12:20        /user/xxxx/rhipeTest/ibm.n_1361467245357.dat
drwxr-xr-x   - xxxxx supergroup          0 2013-02-22 11:47 /user/xxxx/test
12:03:58.412 [sendParams-0] DEBUG org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client - IPC Client (47)        connection to xxxx/xxxxx from tenglin sending #15
12:03:58.413 [IPC Client (47) connection to xxxx from xxxxx]         DEBUG org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client - IPC Client (47) connection to          xxxxx/xxxxx from xxxxx got value #15
12:03:58.414 [main] DEBUG org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RPC - Call: getListing 2
-rw-r--r--   2 tenglin supergroup       5092 2013-02-22 11:47        /user/xxxxx/test/aa.us_1361551612607.dat
-rw-r--r--   2 tenglin supergroup       5125 2013-02-22 11:47 /user/xxxxx/test/aapl.q_1361551612607.dat
....
```

Comment: What are the current values of `HADOOP_ROOT_LOGGER` and `HADOOP_JHS_LOGGER`?

Comment: sorry there was a mistake in the original post. i have this in the hadoop-env.sh file

export HADOOP_ROOT_LOGGER=WARN,DRFA
export HADOOP_JHS_LOGGER=WARN,JSA

Yet I still see "DEBUG" statements in the console

Comment: @cs_newbie did you ever find the solution to removing this debug message?